# Weird camera issue on samsung S4

Tags: java, android, camera

I have an app where I am using Camera intent to capture image and use it for further purpose, problem is on every phone i tested it works (nexus 6p,HTC One m8,S5,redmi 1s) but on S4 the camera goes portrait always and after capturing image returns nothing. Below is the code i m using

```
 Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_OWNER);
 }
```

And to get the image captured , using following simple code

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_OWNER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        CircularImageView circularImageView = (CircularImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgViewParking);
        circularImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        mOwnerImage = imageBitmap;
    }

}
```

Not sure what is wrong with samsung S4 camera software , how to solve it ?

Comment: "after capturing image returns nothing" -- what do you mean by this? In general, camera apps are unreliable, and you are delegating the picture-taking work to a camera app. It is very unlikely that you can "solve" this, and you will encounter other problems with other camera apps (both pre-installed and ones installed by users). `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is for when you would *like* a picture but can live without it.

Comment: @CommonsWare does that mean I have a way where i can force it to absolutely return with an image ? Also I get image empty is the problem

Comment: "does that mean I have a way where i can force it to absolutely return with an image ?" -- no. You are encountering a bug in an app. You cannot snap your fingers and make the bug go away by magic.

Comment: Ha ha I know , thanks anyways